# Acomodar divs uno al lado del otro y centrarlos en pantalla

Tags: css

Tengo un php que va mostrando contenido en un div, el cual se replica segun los resultados. es decir si la consulta a bd arroja un resultado, lo muestra, si arroja dos o mas resultados, tambien los muestra de la misma forma, cada uno en su div.
El Problema es que : Me pone Un Div Debajo de Otro, y Con La Condicion Float: lefth, por ejemplo,
se van al costado de la pantalla (de izquierda a derecha en este caso), segun la cantidad de divs mostrados y cantidad que entren en la pantalla, el resto se van mostrando en una segunda fila de igual manera.
Lo que yo quiero es que: Si Hay un div, lo muestre centrado, si hay dos que tambien los muestre uno al lado del otro tambien

```css
.jugada {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00F7F4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}

.partido {
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
echo("<center><link rel='stylesheet' type= 'text/css' href='jugadas.css'> 

       <div class=jugada>
       
         <div class=numero>$numero</div>
         <div class=usuario>$usuario</div>

<!--------------------------------------- Partido 1 ---------------------------->

          <div class=partido>
            <div class=equipo><img src=$p1e1></div>
            <div class=pronostico>$p1</div>
            <div class=equipo><img src=$p1e2></div>                 
          </div> 

          <br>
```

centrados, igual si hay tres o mas hasta cubrir el ancho de la pantalla y empezar abajo una nueva linea tambien centrada.

Los divs son iguales en tamaño y forma antes que me pregunten, en realidad, es el mismo div que cambia el contenido interior.

Alguna idea para compartir? se los agradezco. Abrazo.

Comment: No Puedo Usar un margin automatico  porque eso haría que no pueda poner un margen para que no esten uno al lado del otro separados por ejemplo x 10px.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con **display flex** en row (filas) y *justify y align*:

```css
.jugada {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*CON ALIGN Y JUSTIFY SIEMPRE ALINEARA LOS ELEMENTOS HIJOS AL CENTRO EN X Y Y*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00F7F4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}

.numero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 2px;
}

.usuario {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
}

.partido {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2px;
}

.equipo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px;
}

.pronostico {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=jugada>

  <div class=numero>$numero</div>
  <div class=usuario>$usuario</div>

  <!--------------------------------------- Partido 1 ---------------------------->

  <div class=partido>
    <div class=equipo><img src=$p1e1></div>
    <div class=pronostico>$p1</div>
    <div class=equipo><img src=$p1e2></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dime si te sirbio.

Comment: Amigo como va, no me dio resultado.

Comment: Que no te funciono? ejecuta la respuesta que te di, ahí veras como se comporta el código que adjunte.

Comment: a ok interpretaste mal la pregunta por lo que veo en la demo de tu codigo igual veo que el div padre si hace lo que quiero en un rato veo si puedo adaptarlo y te digo.